# Reading a CAPTCHA with opencv and pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, captcha, python-tesseract

I am trying to improve an image in order to making the text more readable for OCR, but the problem is that some images have some missing pixels and OCR doesn't recognized it.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import pytesseract
import numpy as np


img = cv.imread("image1.jpeg")
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

threshold = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 57, 13)

x = 255 - threshold

kernel = np.ones((3, 3),np.uint8)
closing = cv.morphologyEx(x, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

captcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(closing, config="--psm 3")
print(captcha)

cv.imshow('close', closing)
cv.imshow('thresh', threshold)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the original image

[image]

This is threshold image

[image]

And this is the result after using closing morph

[image]

For some reason OCR returns the string `le eth g`

Any idea of how can I improve my code?

Comment: You have a very light-gray border around the thresholded image., which is pretty weird since that image should be a binary (only black or white) image. That might be introducing some noise. You could draw a white rectangle around the image. Also, you don't need to do `x = 255 - threshold`, you can pass the `THRESH_BINARY_INV` flag to `adaptiveThreshold` and that should automatically invert the mask for you. Lastly,  Tesseract needs black text on a white background.

Comment: Did you try to invert the 'closing morph' image before applying OCR on it?

Comment: @stateMachine Thanks for ur response, as you suggested I used THRESH_BINARY_INV and also I used ```result = cv.bitwise_not(closing)``` to invert the closing morph to convert the text to black and the backgrount to white, but now OCR returns the string ```Treas``` for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes preprocessing is not needed for the input images. When I tried the input image you gave:

[image]

I used the code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import pytesseract


img = cv.imread("/home/yns/Downloads/t.jpg")


captcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="--psm 6")
print(captcha)
```

and the result comes out as:

## **TTCo7**

which is almos correct. it would be better to keep in mind tesseract is more accurate for the aligned texts so even in some CAPTCHA texts you get successful results it will not work fine at all.

For the reference here is the output of `tesseract --version`:

```
tesseract 4.1.3  leptonica-1.78.0   libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0  
Found AVX2  
Found AVX  
Found FMA  
Found SSE  
Found libarchive 3.2.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.2 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.1
```